# How to print terminal output to the same line using Python

Tags: terminal, python, python3

I am trying to write a python script that constantly displays it's output to the terminal, but instead of printing out a new line for every output, I would like to have a fixed format where the relevant fields get updated instead of reprinting everything. My goal is to accomplish this in Python if possible. I am working on Kali Linux and using xterm, but I also have access to Ubuntu and the standard terminal that comes with it. Pointers for either platform would be useful. Below are some examples of what I'm trying to do and what I am trying to avoid.

**Before update:**

```
root@user:#~ python ./script.py -option1 a -option2 b

---Amplitude---

Receiver1: 0.53
Receiver2: 0.98
Receiver3: 0.49
```

**After update:**

```
root@user:#~ python ./script.py -option1 a -option2 b

---Amplitude---

Receiver1: 0.99
Receiver2: 0.36
Receiver3: 0.12
```

**What I'm Trying to Avoid:**

```
root@user:#~ python ./script.py -option1 a -option2 b

---Amplitude---

Receiver1: 0.53
Receiver2: 0.98
Receiver3: 0.49

---Amplitude---

Receiver1: 0.99
Receiver2: 0.36
Receiver3: 0.12

---Amplitude---

Receiver1: 0.73
Receiver2: 0.19
Receiver3: 0.04
```

Found a solution with ANSI escape codes. Here is a link to a great [tutorial](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#cursor-navigation).

Comment: You should show us (the relevant parts) of your code if possible.

Comment: There's not really much to it, just three different methods I'm calling that return floats, and I want to nicely display them to the terminal from the same python script.

Comment: I will have access to it tomorrow. I will post it then.

Comment: you need to suppress CR. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Comment: If you've found an answer, the correct Stack-Exchange thing to do would be to post an Answer below. Thank you!

Comment: Roger. Will do tomorrow.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to your question, please.